# Create XML export feed in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

can someone direct me to some documentation how to create custom XML feed in PrestaShop 1.6+. I searched official documentation but I didn't find what I needed.

The task is easy - create custom XML feed from which can other e-shop takes the products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get list of products using `getProducts()` then use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/simplexml) for generating xml.

```
include('config/config.inc.php');
include('init.php'); 
$productObj = new Product();
$products = $productObj -> getProducts($id_lang, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'DESC' );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');
foreach($products as $product) {
$productXml = $xml->addChild('product');
$productXml->addChild('id', $product->id);
$productXml->addChild('name', $product->name);
$productXml->addChild('description', $product->description);
}
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
print($xml->asXML());
```

Output will be..

```
<xml>
   <product>
         <id>ID</id>
         <name>NAME</name>
         <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </product>
   <product>
         <id>ID</id>
         <name>NAME</name>
         <description>DESCRIPTION</description>
   </product>
   ...
   ...
   ...
</xml>
```

see function `getProducts()` description in classes/Product.php to know about the parameters.

```
/**
* Get all available products
*
* @param integer $id_lang Language id
* @param integer $start Start number
* @param integer $limit Number of products to return
* @param string $order_by Field for ordering
* @param string $order_way Way for ordering (ASC or DESC)
* @return array Products details
*/
public static function getProducts($id_lang, $start, $limit, $order_by, $order_way, $id_category = false,
    $only_active = false, Context $context = null) {...}
```

You can place xml.php file with in your prestashop root directory and can access this xml by visiting or sending request to `yourdomain.com/xml.php`.

Or if you want to create your module for xml then you need to place the code in your front controller and then you can access the xml file by visiting `yourdomain.com/index.php?fc=module&module=<ModuleName>&controller=<XMLFunction>`.
Read [Prestashop Documentation](http://developers.prestashop.com/module/05-CreatingAPrestaShop17Module/02-CreatingAFirstModule.html#id1) to know more about prestashop module structure.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for response, but I'm missing other thing - how to create in module end-point address where will be XML available? E.g. some URL with my XML will exist.

Comment: Answer Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day :)